# Who killed the child?

Tags: mystery

Here's a puzzle. You will probably find this out easily :)

A family lives in a round cabin. The kid's mom and dad go outside. When they come back, their son is dead. The butcher said he was cutting meat. The maid said she was dusting the house. The butler claimed he was cleaning the corners. Who killed the child?

Comment: Welcome to [SE].  I recommend that you use titles that say at least a little bit about what the question is about; e.g., ‘‘Solving a murder with three suspects’’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Butler,

Because

> The house is cornerless. So the butler is lying ...

Comment: yep! you got it

Comment: @CoolDude6116 probably should've said round to make it less obvious

Comment: okay lemme change it

Comment: lol i thought i did something wrong. i knew it was obvious :)

Comment: how do we know that the liar is the killer?

Comment: @ Geoftrue, the butler may have been screwing the maid, and the meat the butcher was cutting was the son.

Answer (score 6):

The murderer was

> the father

because

> an average family can’t afford household staff,
> let alone a three-person staff for a three-person family. 
> This family must be rich. 
> But rich families generally don’t live in cabins. 
> A rich family with a three-person household staff
> certainly wouldn’t live in a one-room cabin. 
> So we can conclude that
>
> - The family is in hiding. 
>   They are probably criminals;
>   e.g., the father is probably a drug kingpin,
>   or some other sort of gangster.
>
>     *(Hmmm. 
>     Is “gangster” a politically incorrect term these days? 
>     Would “mobster” be better? or worse?)*
>
>   The cabin probably has multiple rooms. 
>   For example, a four-room round cabin might look something like this:
>    [image: four-room round cabin]
>   So there are at least four, and maybe twelve, corners
>   for the butler to clean.
>
> The son was scheming to assassinate his father
> and take over the criminal enterprise. 
> So Dad killed his son in pre-emptive self-defense. 
> He put a slow-acting poison into the young man’s breakfast,
> and then went for a walk to establish an alibi while the poison took effect.

Of course, nowadays,

> it could just as well have been the mom.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate of a ‘‘lateral thinking’’ puzzle, I should be allowed to use lateral thinking here, too.